# ImageOptimizer - jpegtran is not executable

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, image

I installed the extension [ImageOptimizer](https://www.apptrian.com/image-optimizer-for-magento). I noticed that it is not working, progress is still at 0% so I activated error logging in the extension and get this:

> jpegtran is not executable.

I executed `which jpegtran` but there is no output.

The **lib** folder has all necessary permissions:

```
mycompany@s64:/var/customers/webs/mycompany/test/lib/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer$ ls -lah
insgesamt 24K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mycompany mycompany 4,0K Feb  4 18:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 mycompany mycompany 4,0K Feb  4 18:23 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mycompany mycompany   75 Feb  4 18:23 elf32 -> ../../../.modman/apptrian-image-optimizer/lib/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/elf32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mycompany mycompany   75 Feb  4 18:23 elf64 -> ../../../.modman/apptrian-image-optimizer/lib/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/elf64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mycompany mycompany   75 Feb  4 18:23 win32 -> ../../../.modman/apptrian-image-optimizer/lib/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/win32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mycompany mycompany   75 Feb  4 18:23 win64 -> ../../../.modman/apptrian-image-optimizer/lib/Apptrian/ImageOptimizer/win64
```

So I installed the binary and it still gives me the same error that it does not have permission **jpegtran is not executable.**, even though this are the set permission `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31K Okt 20 2016 jpegtran`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by asking my hoster to install jpegtran, gifsicle and optipng.

I also had to set the absolute path to the binary in the extension settings.

[image]

Comment: from my experience this extension has very low efficiency. remove it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing jpegtran on your system with:

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs`

Answer (score 1):

install **jpegtran** on your system

If you are on **Debian/Ubuntu**:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs
```

If you are on **Fedora/Centos/RedHat**:

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-utils
```

Comment: I installed it and it still gives me the same error that it does not have permission `jpegtran is not executable.` even though this are the set permission `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     31K Okt 20  2016 jpegtran`